# ASP.NET 5 RC - Error CS0121 ambiguous call’s (in own class)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have started with ASP.NET 5 and just updated to RC (VS2015).
By my start, I have placed some central methods and data-definitions in the startup.cs-file (where I don’t have problems with it).
Now, I want to use an own class-file for my own code and therefore have added a new class-file to the project (in VS) and copy-pasted my code from startup.cs in my own class file (and commented the code in startup.cs of course).

Now, I have duplicate definitions of the methods to themselves.
Error e.g.:

> M:\SW\VS_2015\WEB\MGTest2\src\MGTest2\ZentraleFunktionenVariablen.cs(280,52,280,76):
>   DNX Core 5.0 error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following
>   methods or properties:
>   'ZentraleFunktionenVariablen.MG_Funktionen.GetDynamicIdentification(DateTime)'
>   and
>   'ZentraleFunktionenVariablen.MG_Funktionen.GetDynamicIdentification(DateTime)

In the error-window, I can see **two** projects in the project column:
MGTest2.DNX **4.5.1**
**and**
MGTest2.DNX **Core 5.0**

So… it seems, as the methods are registered for the two runtimes, what causes the problem and some other configurations has to be done to solve the problem.
I don’t have found any information to the problem yet.

Note:
The class-file is stored in the root to the project (where also startup.cs is stored).
I have tried to store the file in an own project-directory, what not solves the problem.

Comment: I have this problem too, which is caused by Resharper. Do you happen to have Resharper too?

Comment: Thanks for your comment (so I know, that's not a problem related to my configuration only. And... no, I don't work with Resharper.  I have posted the problem also in the MS forum in the meantime, b.t.w.

Comment: Does running `dnu build` in your project directory produce the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the problem / solution.

I had encapsulated the methods in the class-file in a further class.
After I have changed that (methods directly in the class definition of the class-file) it seems to work now.